# 2 part stored proc is successful when run piecemeal, unsuccessful when run all at once

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

See code below.
When I run parts #1 and #2 separately, they work as planned: I get the expected 'Y' value in the [InsertFlag] field.

But when I run them together by executing the entire sp, I do not get the expected 'Y' value.

My best guess is that regardless of the order in which I place these two statements, #2 executes first.  This populates [SCD_Type2_EndDate], and when #1 tests that field for NULL, it fails and therefore doesn't update the [InsertFlag] field.

If my guess is correct then I need to find a way to force these two statements to run in order. I tried adding 'GO' after the 1st statement but receive the following error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure
>   etl_Update_SetExpiryDate_adName, Line
>   19 Incorrect syntax near ';'. Msg 102,
>   Level 15, State 1, Line 23 Incorrect
>   syntax near 'END'.

So, how can I fix this?

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE etl_Update_SetExpiryDate_adName
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

--1.
UPDATE 
 amlrr.wtName
SET
 InsertFlag = 'Y'
FROM 
 amlrr.wtName wtN
INNER JOIN amlrr.adName adN
 ON wtN.StageID = adN.StageID
WHERE 
 adN.SCD_Type2_EndDate IS NULL
AND
 wtN.FullName <> adN.FullName

GO
--2.

UPDATE 
 amlrr.adName
SET
 SCD_Type2_EndDate = getdate()
FROM 
 amlrr.adName adN
INNER JOIN amlrr.wtName wtN
 ON adN.StageID = wtN.StageID
WHERE 
 adN.SCD_Type2_EndDate IS NULL
AND
 adN.FullName <> wtN.FullName








END
GO
```

Comment: Please format your code according to the guidelines. It's impossible to read this way.

Comment: I agree.  I guess I thought it would magically format itself.  I'll read up on how to do that before my next post.

Comment: False alarm, I'm an idiot.  I accidentally created a copy of this sp in the dbo schema, and I was testing by running the one in the amlrr schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the GO after first update statement.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE etl_Update_SetExpiryDate_adName
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

--1.
UPDATE 
 amlrr.wtName
SET
 InsertFlag = 'Y'
FROM 
 amlrr.wtName wtN
INNER JOIN amlrr.adName adN
 ON wtN.StageID = adN.StageID
WHERE 
 adN.SCD_Type2_EndDate IS NULL
AND
 wtN.FullName <> adN.FullName

--2.

UPDATE 
 amlrr.adName
SET
 SCD_Type2_EndDate = getdate()
FROM 
 amlrr.adName adN
INNER JOIN amlrr.wtName wtN
 ON adN.StageID = wtN.StageID
WHERE 
 adN.SCD_Type2_EndDate IS NULL
AND
 adN.FullName <> wtN.FullName
END
GO
```

Comment: Removing the GO has no effect.  Same problem.